# Populating a class in Kotlin with user input

Tags: kotlin

I am brand new to Kotlin and am taking a Mobile App Development course.
In this project we're trying to create a class and populate the information with a user input. I've followed with the book as far as creating the class but Im having issues filling it.

The way I'm thinking it should process would be:
Class creation
call a GetStudentInfo function
information filled out and then returned back

But I cannot for the life of my figure this out. My text book only has creating classes and populating with static information. Nothing relating to user input.

Thank you so much for the help.

```
class Student
{
    var FName: String?=null
    var LName: String?=null
    var Street_Add: String?=null
    var City: String?=null
    var State: String?=null
    var Zip: Int?=null
    var GPA: Double?=null
    var Major: String?=null

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
GetStudentInfo()
    var StudentInfo = Student()

    println(StudentInfo.FName)
}

fun GetStudentInfo()
{
    var StudentInfo = Student()
    print("Please enter the student's first name: ")
    StudentInfo.FName = readLine()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [kotlin.io readLine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) as you have tried. You just need to cast what you need. If you want to take Double just do `val value = readLine().toDouble()` You can also create functions for simplicity such as,

`fun readInt() = readLine()!!.toInt()`

Or, you may use legacy scanner way.

```
 with(Scanner(System.`in`)){
      print("Please enter the student's first name: ")
      StudentInfo.FName = nextLine()
 }
```

EDIT: (Sample Program)

```
fun main() {
    val studentInfo = getStudentInfo()
    println(studentInfo)
}

fun getStudentInfo(): Student {
    val student = Student()
    return student.apply {
        print("Please enter the student's first name: ")
        FName = readLine()
        print("Please enter the student's last name: ")
        LName = readLine()
        print("Please enter the student's street add: ")
        Street_Add = readLine()
        print("Please enter the student's city: ")
        City = readLine()
        print("Please enter the student's state: ")
        State = readLine()
        print("Please enter the student's zip: ")
        Zip = readLine()?.toInt()
        print("Please enter the student's gpa: ")
        GPA = readLine()?.toDouble()
        print("Please enter the student's major: ")
        Major = readLine()
    }
}

data class Student(
    var FName: String? = null,
    var LName: String? = null,
    var Street_Add: String? = null,
    var City: String? = null,
    var State: String? = null,
    var Zip: Int? = null,
    var GPA: Double? = null,
    var Major: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Ok perfect! I am going to implement this and see what I come up with!
As far as a GetStudentInfo function and eventually a GetTeacherInfo... I cannot seem to pass the information back and forth for some reason? It spits out an error about unresolved references and the like?

Comment: Just change your function that returns StudentInfo.  fun GetStudentInfo(): Student { ... return StudentInfo }

Comment: I guess maybe that's where my issue is. Im coming from python which is a bit different than this. I have created my class and all the properties.. I am now trying to call a function to populate those properties but for some reason it's not working properly :(

Comment: @VeritasCurat check my new edit, and try that code.

Comment: ah ha!
Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I see a keyword in there that my textbook had not covered which is the "student.apply" line.. I will do some research on that - but that is perfect and closes the gaps i wasn't sure about!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: In this case apply simply prevents you to write student.FName, student.LName for each instance, instead it makes you use the instances like you are in the scope of Student class.

Comment: A small correction: calling a function like `toInt()` is a **conversion**, not a **cast**.  A conversion gives an object of the required type, while a cast (such as `as Int`) promises the compiler that the value already _is_ the requried type -- which in this case it's not, so would give a runtime error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, toInt() is just an extension function that calls parseInt, thanks for the remark, should be careful while using it.